# Flickr backup/sync with new OS X Photos app

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, photos.app, flickr

Searching for a solution how to use the 1 TB free flickr storage to sync my photo library. I use the new Apple OS X Photos app and don't want to sync with iCloud (just 5GB free storage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the FlickrUploadr application available at [this link](https://flickr.com/tools/downloadmac) (which is visible at the bottom right of Flickr's [Camera Roll](https://www.flickr.com/cameraroll) feature).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Surprisingly I didn't see it earlier.